# Visual Studio designer keeps messing control up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, designer

I have a custom control on a user control, and whenever I go in and edit the user control in designer (i.e. move some controls around, add controls, etc.) more likely than not, the designer.cs ends up removing the creation for my custom control. The line that keeps getting removed is `this.MtbZip = new ClickableMaskedTextBox();`. For the sake of discussion, this control was added by dragging and dropping from the Toolbox panel. I did not manually add it to the designer.cs

It seems that oft as not Visual Studio removes the line when the control is rebuilt and I end up with a null reference when the rest of the designer.cs is executed.

I really don't know what to try. I did find one question that recommended making sure that the Form.Load method was not run when in `DesignMode`, but as you can see, I'm not utilizing any Form.Loads here. At present I just keep replacing the line in the designer.cs that creates the control, which works . . . until Visual Studio decides it's time to remove the line again.

My custom control:

```
    public partial class ClickableMaskedTextBox : MaskedTextBox
    {
        [DllImport("user32")]
        private extern static int GetCaretPos(out Point p);

        public enum MaskType { None, Zipcode }

        [Category("Appearance")]
        [Description("The mask for the text box")]
        public MaskType CurrentMask
        {
            get
            {
                return currentMask;
            }
            set
            {
                if (currentMask == value) return;
                switch (value)
                {
                    case MaskType.None:
                        Mask = string.Empty;
                        break;

                    case MaskType.Zipcode:
                        Mask = "99999-9999";
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                currentMask = value;
            }
        }

        private MaskType currentMask;

        internal ClickableMaskedTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Click += ClickableMaskedTextBox_Click;
        }

        private void ClickableMaskedTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCaretPos(out Point caret);
            int caretPosition = GetCharIndexFromPosition(caret);
            MaskFormat orig = TextMaskFormat;
            TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
            if (caretPosition > Text.Length) Select(Text.Length, 0);
            TextMaskFormat = orig;
        }
    }
```

The designer.cs it is used in:

```
    partial class CtlUSAddress
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.TbAddrLine1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.LblAddr1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.LblLine2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.TbAddrLine2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.LblCity = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.CmbState = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.LblState = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.LblZip = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.CmbCity = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.MtbZip = new ClickableMaskedTextBox();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // TbAddrLine1
            // 
            this.TbAddrLine1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.TbAddrLine1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 3);
            this.TbAddrLine1.Name = "TbAddrLine1";
            this.TbAddrLine1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 20);
            this.TbAddrLine1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // LblAddr1
            // 
            this.LblAddr1.AutoSize = true;
            this.LblAddr1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
            this.LblAddr1.Name = "LblAddr1";
            this.LblAddr1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 4, 0, 0);
            this.LblAddr1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(36, 17);
            this.LblAddr1.TabIndex = 5;
            this.LblAddr1.Text = "Line 1";
            // 
            // LblLine2
            // 
            this.LblLine2.AutoSize = true;
            this.LblLine2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 26);
            this.LblLine2.Name = "LblLine2";
            this.LblLine2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 4, 0, 0);
            this.LblLine2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(36, 17);
            this.LblLine2.TabIndex = 6;
            this.LblLine2.Text = "Line 2";
            // 
            // TbAddrLine2
            // 
            this.TbAddrLine2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.TbAddrLine2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 29);
            this.TbAddrLine2.Name = "TbAddrLine2";
            this.TbAddrLine2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 20);
            this.TbAddrLine2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // LblCity
            // 
            this.LblCity.AutoSize = true;
            this.LblCity.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 52);
            this.LblCity.Name = "LblCity";
            this.LblCity.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 4, 0, 0);
            this.LblCity.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 17);
            this.LblCity.TabIndex = 7;
            this.LblCity.Text = "City";
            // 
            // CmbState
            // 
            this.CmbState.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            this.CmbState.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.CmbState.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 82);
            this.CmbState.Name = "CmbState";
            this.CmbState.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(47, 21);
            this.CmbState.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // LblState
            // 
            this.LblState.AutoSize = true;
            this.LblState.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 79);
            this.LblState.Name = "LblState";
            this.LblState.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 4, 0, 0);
            this.LblState.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 17);
            this.LblState.TabIndex = 8;
            this.LblState.Text = "State";
            // 
            // LblZip
            // 
            this.LblZip.AutoSize = true;
            this.LblZip.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 106);
            this.LblZip.Name = "LblZip";
            this.LblZip.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 4, 0, 0);
            this.LblZip.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(22, 17);
            this.LblZip.TabIndex = 9;
            this.LblZip.Text = "Zip";
            // 
            // CmbCity
            // 
            this.CmbCity.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.CmbCity.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.CmbCity.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 55);
            this.CmbCity.Name = "CmbCity";
            this.CmbCity.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 21);
            this.CmbCity.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // MtbZip
            // 
            this.MtbZip.AllowPromptAsInput = false;
            this.MtbZip.CurrentMask = AccountingApp.Controls.ClickableMaskedTextBox.MaskType.Zipcode;
            this.MtbZip.CutCopyMaskFormat = System.Windows.Forms.MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
            this.MtbZip.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 109);
            this.MtbZip.Mask = "99999-9999";
            this.MtbZip.Name = "MtbZip";
            this.MtbZip.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(67, 20);
            this.MtbZip.TabIndex = 10;
            this.MtbZip.TextMaskFormat = System.Windows.Forms.MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
            this.MtbZip.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.MtbZip_Leave);
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.LblAddr1, 0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.MtbZip, 1, 4);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.LblLine2, 0, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.CmbState, 1, 3);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.CmbCity, 1, 2);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.LblCity, 0, 2);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.LblZip, 0, 4);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.TbAddrLine2, 1, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.LblState, 0, 3);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.TbAddrLine1, 1, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 5;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 137);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 11;
            // 
            // CtlUSAddress
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
            this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 137);
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 137);
            this.Name = "CtlUSAddress";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 137);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TbAddrLine1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label LblAddr1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label LblLine2;
        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TbAddrLine2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label LblCity;
        public System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox CmbState;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label LblState;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label LblZip;
        public System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox CmbCity;
        public ClickableMaskedTextBox MtbZip;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
    }
```

Comment: The default constructor of a control should be public.

Comment: Is the `MtbZip` property public or internal? If so, you should probably decorate it with the `[Browsable(false)]` and `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]` attributes to ensure that the designer doesn't try to (de)serialise it.

Comment: To expand on Hans' answer: _..or else the designer can't access it._

Comment: Why thank you. I wasn't aware of that requirement. I will implement it.

Comment: In my test, just need to delete the code `this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);`and`this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;` in the "ClickableMaskedTextBox.Designer.cs".